# Create Async Await Queue in C# windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, queue, async-await

I am having a List View of Images. Depending upon user's key word, the list is filtered and refined list is added as source of list view. Once, the source is added, I am using Async/Await method to download images in listview from internet.

This is my problem: Once the user enters a keyword, A list is created and async call is created. when new keyword is entered, Another list is replaced and new async call is added parallel to previous one. There is a considerable lag in UI when number of async calls added more.

This is what I want. I need to create a queue of async calls of size say 5. when sixth call is added. It should cancel the first async call and get added in queue.

Comment: Do you even need a queue? Maybe you just need to cancel *all* download tasks that are no longer needed with the new list.

Comment: That's my second option if the above scenario is not possible. Can u explain me how to cancel all the previous calls when new list is added??

Comment: Use a `CancellationToken`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a queue; since each keyword replaces the previous one, you only need one download going at a time.

This can be accomplished using `CancellationTokenSource`. Here's one example approach:

```
private CancellationTokenSource _cts;
private async Task RefreshListAsync(string keyword)
{
  if (_cts != null)
    _cts.Cancel();
  _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
  var result = await DownloadListAsync(keyword, _cts.Token);
  _cts.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  MyList = result;
}
```

Comment: - Stephen Cleary. Unfortunately the previous call is not cancelling. I have used your approach only.

Comment: @AasiqDx: You have to observe the token in `DownloadListAsync`. Normally, this is done by passing the token to whatever object is doing the network call.